# ShowSoftInput show the sof keybord only once

Tags: java, android

In my app I would like to edit some text in an EditText view starting in

```
setFocusableInTouchMode(false).
```

I want to do this by pressing a single button to toggle between "edit mode" and "readonly mode".

I am using `showSoftInput`and `hideSoftInputFromWindow`. Everything works but the problem that I can't solve is that the soft keyboard appears automatically only the first time. On repeated editing (which means pressing the button repeatedly on and off) the soft keyboard reappear only manually. 
Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_act"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/OCRtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean TextFound = true;
    boolean ON_EDIT = false;
    EditText OCRtext;
    InputMethodManager imm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        OCRtext = findViewById(R.id.OCRtext);
        OCRtext.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        OCRtext.setText(R.string.Testo);

        imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_edit: {
                if (TextFound) {
                    if(!ON_EDIT) {
                        ON_EDIT = true;
                        //findViewById(R.id.main_act).requestFocus();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Modifiche abilitate",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        OCRtext.setFocusable(true);
                        OCRtext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        OCRtext.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                        OCRtext.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        OCRtext.requestFocus(); //con questo la keyb compare sempre solo col tap
                        imm.showSoftInput(OCRtext.getRootView(),2);
                    }
                    else {
                        ON_EDIT = false;
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(OCRtext.getWindowToken(),0);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Modifiche disabilitate",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        OCRtext.setFocusable(false);
                        OCRtext.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                        OCRtext.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        OCRtext.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

                    }
                }
            }

            case R.id.action_save: {
                return true;
            }

            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatted the question and modified the grammar